# Showing measurability of composite function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous map and $p':\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $p'(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       a & : x=0\\
       p(x) & : x\neq 0.
     \end{array}
   \right.$

I want to show that $p'$ is Lebesgue measurable, i.e. for all $L\in\mathcal{L}$, with $\mathcal{L}$ the Lebesgue sigma-algebra, we have $p'^{-1}(L)\in\mathcal{L}$.
If $a\notin L$, then $p'(L)\in\mathcal{L}$ since $p$ is measurable.
But what if $a\in L$?

Comment: Compare $p(L)$ (which is measurable) with $p'(L)$, and see if the difference could ever make a measurable set non-measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

$$p^{-1}(L) = p^{-1}(\{a\} \cup L \setminus \{a\})= p^{-1}(\{a\}) \cup p^{-1}(L \setminus \{a\}) = \{0\}\cup p^{-1}(L \setminus \{0\}),$$

which enables to conclude as $\{b\}$ is the complement of the open set $(-\infty,b) \cup (b, \infty)$ for any $b \in \mathbb R.$

Comment: Do we know that $\{a\}\in\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: @JohnWaid See my response update on your question.

Comment: since this is accepted answer - just fix $a$-$0$ to be in appropriate places

Comment: @dEmigOd That appears to be due to my mistake. I meant of course $a\in L$ in my question

Answer (score 0):

$\{a\} \in \mathcal{L}$ -it is a complement of open set.

Let $A, B \in \mathcal{L}$, then $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{L}$, and indeed $A \setminus B = A \cap B^C = (A^C \cup B)^C$, i.e. in $\sigma$-algebra ($\mathcal{L}$).

So, in case $a \in L$ take $L = (L\setminus\{a\}) \cup \{a\}$, and pull it back, you have $$p'^{-1}(L) = p^{-1}(L\setminus\{a\}) \cup \left(p^{-1}(\{a\}) \cup\{0\}\right)$$, the first one is measurable set, as pre-image of measurable set under measurable function, and $p^{-1}(\{a\})$ is also measurable for the same reason, $\{0\}$ is closed and hence measurable

Comment: But what if there are $x$ such that $p(x)=a$, then $p'^{-1}({a})\neq \{0\}$

Comment: That's a nice way to solve things, so reviewer is invested.

Comment: and may be if $p(0)=a$, then everything is trivial